# Using OAuth2 and ZF3-MVC to protect REST API

Tags: zend-framework, oauth-2.0, zend-framework-mvc, zend-framework3, zf3

I'm trying to get https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-oauth2 working with my **ZF3-MVC Application** (ok, one solution could be to wait Apigility update).

I have successfully implemented the oauth2-server-php (https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php), its zf-oauth2 module support (https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-oauth2) and adapted zf-oauth2 client for ZF3 (https://github.com/API-Skeletons/zf-oauth2-client).

However, I'm totaly stuck now trying to protect my API y following zf-oauth2 module's recommandation:

> You can protect your API using the following code (for instance, at the top of a controller):

```cs
if (!$this->server->verifyResourceRequest(OAuth2Request::createFromGlobals()))
{
    // Not authorized return 401 error
    $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(401);
    return;
}
```

> where $this->server is an instance of OAuth2\Server (see the AuthController.php).

I've read this post ([Using ZF2 Oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996243/using-zf2-oauth2)) but it's not compliant with ZF3. I guess there's a more efficient way rather than copying/pasting zf-oauth2 module's controller and factory to instantiate the server from scratch.

Would anyone have a clue on how to implement the instance of OAuth2\Server in my API controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally did it by my own. As I spent a significant amount time on this and saw that others where also looking for a solution, here is how I did it.

At first, I suggest you read https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/in-depth-guide/models-and-servicemanager/ if you're not familiar with Dependency Injection and Factories (this was my case).

**module.config.php**

```php
// In module/YourModule/config/module.config.php:
namespace YourAppNamespace;

use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\YourController::class => Factory\YourControllerFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'service_manager' => [ /** Your Service Manager Config **/ ]        
    'router' => [ /** Your Router Config */ ]
    'view_manager' => [ /** Your ViewManager Config */ ],
];
```

**YourControllerFactory.php**

```php
// In module/YourModule/src/Controller/YourControllerFactory.php:
namespace YourAppNamespace\Factory;

use YourAppNamespace\Controller\YourController;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

class YourControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @param string             $requestedName
     * @param null|array         $options
     *
     * @return YourController
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $controllerPluginManager = $container;
        $serviceManager          = $controllerPluginManager->get('ServiceManager');

        // Requires zf-campus/zf-oauth2
        $server   = $serviceManager->get('ZF\OAuth2\Service\OAuth2Server');
        $provider = $serviceManager->get('ZF\OAuth2\Provider\UserId');

        return new YourController($server, $provider);
    }
}
```

**YourController.php**

```php
// In module/YourModule/src/Controller/YourController.php:
namespace YourAppNamespace\Controller;

use ZF\OAuth2\Controller\AuthController;
use OAuth2\Request as OAuth2Request;
use ZF\OAuth2\Provider\UserId\UserIdProviderInterface;

class YourController extends AuthController
{
    public function __construct($serverFactory, UserIdProviderInterface $userIdProvider)
    {
        parent::__construct($serverFactory, $userIdProvider);
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $server = call_user_func($this->serverFactory, "oauth");

        if (!$server->verifyResourceRequest(OAuth2Request::createFromGlobals())) {
            // Failure
            $response = $server->getResponse();
            return $this->getApiProblemResponse($response);
        }

        // Success
        echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'It works!'));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!